# How to get the quiz answers from array list?

Tags: android, text, arraylist, radio-button

I'm new to android. I'm doing a project on quiz app. I have problem on displaying the question and answers.

My problem is that I have stored the question and answers in the array. The question and answer is displaying but not in order.

I got the question and answers from database. They are coming in order but in my array list it's not in order. The question and answer are not matching.

How to display it in correct order for question by matching correct order.

Please help me and thanks a lot in advance.

`code`

```
      protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();  
        ques1=new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(ques1));

        System.out.println(" Question array:"+ques1);
        String[] quesArr = new String [ques1.size()];
        quesArr = ques1.toArray(quesArr);
        for(String s: quesArr){
            Collections.sort(ques1, new Comparator<String>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return 0;
                }

            });
        System.out.println("All Array Questions:"+s);
            final TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt);
            final String text=ques1.get(j).toString();
            System.out.println("Array:"+text);
            txtque.setText(text);
        }

        try { 
          int i = 0;
        //  answ1=new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(answ1));
        JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);

        String answer = c.getString(TAG_ANSW);

        System.out.println("Checking ::"+answer);
        answ=answer;
        HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        answ1.add(answer);
            System.out.println(" Answer array:"+answ1);
            String[] answArr = new String [answ1.size()];
            answArr = answ1.toArray(answArr);
            for(String A: answArr){
                Collections.sort(answ1, new Comparator<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                        return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
                    }
                });
            System.out.println("All Array Answers:"+A);
            }

            final TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt);
            btn_practicerg =(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdgroup);
            btn_practice1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB1);
             btn_practice1.setText(String.valueOf(answArr[0]));
            btn_practice2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB2);
            btn_practice2.setText(String.valueOf(answArr[1]));
            btn_practice3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB3);
            btn_practice3.setText(String.valueOf(answArr[2]));
            btn_practice4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB4);
            btn_practice4.setText(String.valueOf(answArr[3]));

            btn_practicerg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
                {
                    RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);

                }
            });
             } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            btn_practicerg.clearCheck();

            Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn);
            nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                 j++;
                 TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt);
                    txtque.setText(ques1.get(j).toString());                
                 k++;
                 btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get(k).toString());
                 k++;
                 btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get(k).toString());
                 k++;
                 btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get(k).toString());
                 k++;
                 btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get(k).toString());

            }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing the questions in a HashSet, which is not preserving the order. Plus, your comparator always returns 0.

Comment: Im new to android. What changes should i do

Comment: @God'sGrace you are new to java too

Comment: @blackbelt Yes..What changes i should do?

Answer (score 0):

there is another much easier approach to it I would have never choosen hashset I find them very complicated

create a wrapper class 
class qa 
{
String ques;
String and;
}

now create a arraylist of this class type ArrayList and fill the values in this way you can have all data at one place and will ease your task since you are new.

Comment: What i should im new to this..Why im getting this problem